# Javascript onclick function to change all instances of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I am trying to build something where the user clicks on a button, and it changes the background color of all instances of "section" elements on the page. When I realized I couldn't get my code to change multiple sections at once, I reduced it to just one section and still couldn't get it to work.

Here's a reduced version of my code...

```
<section id="colorSection">
    <div id="colorWrap" class="wrap">
        <h1>Choose the color you'd like the demo to be in</h1>
        <div id="colorSelector">
            <button id="black" class="colorButton"></button>
            <button id="white" class="colorButton"></button>
        </div>
   </div>
</section>

<script>
var colorSection = document.getElementById('colorSection');
var blackButton = document.getElementById('black');
var whiteButton = document.getElementById('white');
blackButton.onclick = function(){
colorWrap.style.backgroundColor = "#444;"
}
whiteButton.onclick = function(){
colorWrap.style.backgroundColor = "#efefef;"
}
</script>
```

My logic tells me that...

I have identified a section and turned it into a variable ("colorWrap").

I have identified the buttons and converted them to variables.

I have created a function that triggers when a button is clicked, and it takes the colorWrap section and changes its background color accordingly.

Obviously, this isn't happening. SO- can someone tell me where I'm going wrong in this example, and then perhaps point me in the direction of being able to affect all instances of an element (instead of the one that I identified by its ID) when a button is clicked?

Comment: `colorWrap !== colorSection`. You're declaring `colorSection`, but using `colorWrap`, which is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easily achievable via [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). You can use it's selector feature to select all `<section>` that you want, and apply a style to them:

**For One Section**

```
blackButton.onclick = function(){
    $("section#colorSection").css("background", "#444");
}

whiteButton.onclick = function(){
    $("section#colorSection").css("background", "#efefef");
}
```

**For All Sections**

```
blackButton.onclick = function(){
    $("section").css("background", "#444");
}

whiteButton.onclick = function(){
    $("section").css("background", "#efefef");
}
```

Just use jQuery's selector to select all `<section>`s (or alternately your selector could be something like `section.ColorToggle` so you can specify which sections you want to toggle with a CSS class).

Above, I used the ID to select the specific section, so only that is colored.

Comment: His goal was to color all sections on click, was it not?

Comment: I'll edit my code to reflect that. It seemed like s/he originally wanted it to be all (or several) sections.

Comment: Yes, I want it to affect all sections on my page; I just included a snippet with one section in the example.

Comment: Then use just the `section` selector instead of the `section#colorSection`, but I can edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel Looks like you've been right all the time ; ). I've removed my comments about a single element. (it just seems odd when someone's trying to refer multiple elements with `gEBI()`)

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper variable is wrong (inside the onlick event), also the hex color should have no `;` at the end:

```js
var colorSection = document.getElementById('colorSection');
var blackButton = document.getElementById('black');
var whiteButton = document.getElementById('white');
blackButton.onclick = function () {
    colorSection.style.backgroundColor = "#444"
}
whiteButton.onclick = function () {
    colorSection.style.backgroundColor = "#efefef"
}
```

```html
<section id="colorSection">
    <div id="colorWrap" class="wrap">
         <h1>Choose the color you'd like the demo to be in</h1>

        <div id="colorSelector">
            <button id="black" class="colorButton">Black</button>
            <button id="white" class="colorButton">White</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set colorWrap in any way

```
var colorWrap = document.getElementById('colorWrap');
```

Comment: Yeah, it's actually used in the context of the full page I've built: This is just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('red').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('mainSection').style.backgroundColor = "#ff8800"
    document.getElementById('mainSection').style.color = "#fff"
}
document.getElementById('white').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('mainSection').style.backgroundColor = "#efefef"
    document.getElementById('mainSection').style.color = "#333"
}
```

```html
<section id="mainSection">
    <div id="colorWrap" class="wrap">
         <h1>Choose the color you'd like the demo to be in</h1>
    </div>
 Try It Once
</section>
 <div id="color">
            <button id="red" class="colorButton">Add Color</button>
            <button id="white" class="colorButton">Remove Color</button>
        </div>
```